# How can I get HTTP request headers in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, http-headers, http-request-parameters

In internet, I see only add parameter to HTTP request like below.

```
  this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

I cannot find how can I get HTTP request header params in Angular 4.

Comment: you can look at the network call `request` headers

Comment: I am quite new at angular. Can you give an example?

Comment: have a look at this [**image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kpKB.png)

Comment: Thanks, but i want to take this info to my angular code.

Comment: request headers is something which you are sending in the request, so you should be able to see in the network if you are using the above code mentioned in the post

Answer (score 1):

if this is of any use for someone looking for this answer nowadays:

```
request.headers.forEach(h=> {
console.log(h);
console.log(request.headers.get(h));
})
```

that will print in your console all the header names, with their corresponding values, whenever request is an `HttpRequest`.

I am using it inside my interceptor for implementing a V4 signature in my angular 10 app and it is working ATM.

You get `HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(7), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: null, headers: Map(7)}`
when looking into the `request.headers`content in developer tools because it is lazy loaded, however if you look into it again after running the code I pasted above, you should see in the headers property all your existing headers and their content (that should match what was printed in the console).

*Source: I tried in the console in a running Angular 10 app, while paused in a breakpoint inside the intercept method of an Http Interceptor.*

Comment: didn't get it, how did you dump them?

Answer (score -1):

The Headers class also has a get(name: string) method, which returns a string, as well as other helpful methods for inspecting the headers. From the Angular docs:

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders

```
class HttpHeaders {
  constructor(headers?: string | {...})
  has(name: string): boolean
  get(name: string): string | null
  keys(): string[]
  getAll(name: string): string[] | null
  append(name: string, value: string | string[]): HttpHeaders
  set(name: string, value: string | string[]): HttpHeaders
  delete(name: string, value?: string | string[]): HttpHeaders
}
```

You could also use your browser's developer tools to inspect the request/response headers.

EDIT: It might be helpful if you specify exactly what it is you need to do. Is there a particular header that you need to inspect?

EDIT2: There's also the deprecated Headers class. Not sure which you're using, but there's a lot of overlap in terms of the methods available so it may not even matter.

https://angular.io/api/http/Headers

```
class Headers {
  constructor(headers?: Headers | {...})
  static fromResponseHeaderString(headersString: string): Headers
  append(name: string, value: string): void
  delete(name: string): void
  forEach(fn: (values: string[], name: string | undefined, headers: Map<string, string[]>) => void): void
  get(name: string): string | null
  has(name: string): boolean
  keys(): string[]
  set(name: string, value: string | string[]): void
  values(): string[][]
  toJSON(): {...}
  getAll(name: string): string[] | null
  entries()
}
```